# Using Draggable in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable

I'm not a total n00b, but I am woefully ignorant of modern Javascript. Most of my scant Vue.js experience has been trying to figure this issue out. I open with this, dear internet, to impress upon you that I'd like it if you'd dumb down your answer as dumb you can.

I'm using Laravel 6/Vue 2 to build a kanban board. My HTML for a single list is as follows:

```
                <section id="lists">
                    <div class="list full-height" v-for="list in this.results.tlists">
                        <div contenteditable="true"  @blur="saveTitle('list', $event)" @keydown.enter="saveTitle('list', $event);" class="name">@{{ list.name }}</div>
                            <div class="task" v-for="task in list.tasks">
                                <p contenteditable="true" @blur="saveTitle('task', $event)" @keydown.enter="saveTitle('task', $event)" >@{{ task.name }}</p>
                                <div contenteditable="true" v-bind:style="'background-color: #' + tag.hex_color" v-bind:title=tag.name class="tag" v-for="tag in task.tags">
                                    @{{ tag.name }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

To use Draggable, I start with the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable):

```
<!-- CDNJS :: Sortable (https://cdnjs.com/) -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.8.4/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<!-- CDNJS :: Vue.Draggable (https://cdnjs.com/) -->
<script src="//cdnjs.buttflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.20.0/vuedraggable.umd.min.js"></script>
```

As an aside, Butt to Butt did its thing on the URL for Vue.Draggable. I was initially trying to import from cdnjs.buttflare.com.

Per the instructions, I convert the .list div to a draggable element. This is what the console tells me:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

There's an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/364) that recommends replacing the draggable tag like so:

```
<tbody is="draggable" :list="category.Items" v-bind:element="'tbody'" v-on:move="RowMoved">
```

I turned the draggable element back to a div and replaced the .list line with:

```
<div is="draggable" :list="this.results.tlists" v-bind:element="'div'" class="list full-height" v-for="list in this.results.tlists" v-on:Move="mvList">
```

I'm not familiar with ":list" so I took a guess. The console indicates my guess was not a good one:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.results is undefined"
>
> (found in ) vue.esm.browser.js:627:15
>   [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.results is undefined"
>
> (found in ) vue.esm.browser.js:627:15
>   TypeError: "this.results is undefined" TypeError: "this.results is undefined"

I suspect the reason it's not defined is because the ajax call hasn't run to give it a value. I tried omitting it entirely but got the earlier error message about unknown custom element.

I'm not sure where to go from here. All my attempts at Googling have been so far afield of my situation that they're not helpful. Any insight would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** The definition of the ajax call:

```
    mounted() {
        var token = 'whatever token';
        axios.post("[my dev box]/show-board?id=1", {}, {
            headers: { 'Authorization': "Bearer " + token }
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.results = response.data.data
        });
    }
```

Comment: so, what is `this.results`? where is it defined? where is this *ajax call* you refer to?

Comment: Right, It the result of an ajax call.

Comment: Edited to add the definition of the ajax call.